# Next 13 axios interceptors on server

Tags: authentication, axios, next.js13

I have create axios interceptors for both the client side and server side fetching where iam passing the bearer token. however iam facing some issues for the server side api fetching.Iam using access and refresh tokens.

i) Initially when the page is loaded iam getting a 401 Unauthorized Error but on the page refresh data is fetched

ii) When the token expires the error handler doesnt work and i cant delete the cookie values [iam using use server functions to handle delete and set cookies on the server]

***Axios Interceptors:

---

```
import {AxiosError, AxiosResponse, InternalAxiosRequestConfig} from 'axios';
import { PUBLIC_ENDPOINTS } from '@/_utils/constants';
import TokenService from '@/services/token.service';
import axios from './axios-instance';
import {cookieAuth, cookieData, cookieRefresh, tokenRetries} from "@/_utils/cookies";
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'

const requestHandler =async (request: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
  if (isServer) {
    const { cookies } = (await import('next/headers'))
        , token = cookies().get(cookieAuth)?.value
    console.log('token')

    if (token) {
      request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }
  else{
    const token = TokenService.getLocalAccessToken();
    const refreshToken = TokenService.getLocalRefreshToken();
    if (token && request.url !== `/auth/tokens`) {
      request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    } else {
      request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${refreshToken}`;
    }
  }
  return request;
};

const responseHandler = async(response: AxiosResponse) => {
  if(isServer){
    const { cookies } = (await import('next/headers'))
        , token = cookies().get(cookieAuth)?.value
    response.headers[
        'Authorization'
        ] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  else{
    response.headers[
        'Authorization'
        ] = `Bearer ${TokenService.getLocalAccessToken()}`;
  }

  return response;
};
// eslint-disable-next-line  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
const errorHandler = async (err: any) => {
  const originalConfig = err.config;
  console.log('err')
  if (isServer){
    const { cookies } = (await import('next/headers'));
    const {setServerCookie,removeServerCookie} = (await import('@/services/token.service.server'));
    const retries=Number(cookies().get(tokenRetries))
    console.log('mpo')
    if (
        !PUBLIC_ENDPOINTS.includes(
            originalConfig?.url.split('?')[0]
                ? originalConfig?.url.split('?')[0]
                : originalConfig?.url
        ) &&
        err.response
    ) {
      if (retries > 0 && retries) {
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
          if (originalConfig.url === `/auth/tokens`) {
           await setServerCookie(tokenRetries,(retries-1).toString())
          }
          originalConfig._retry = true;
          try {
            const rs = await axios.get(`/auth/tokens`);
            const { access_token, refresh_token } = rs.data.data.tokens;
            await setServerCookie(cookieRefresh,refresh_token)
            await setServerCookie(cookieAuth,access_token)
            await setServerCookie(tokenRetries,(5).toString())
            return axios(originalConfig);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }
        } else if (err.response.status === 403) {
          console.log('unauthenticated')
        }
      } else {
        await removeServerCookie(cookieData);
        await removeServerCookie(cookieAuth);
        await removeServerCookie(cookieRefresh);
       await removeServerCookie(tokenRetries);

      }
  }
    else{
      const retries = TokenService.getTokenRetries();

      if (
          !PUBLIC_ENDPOINTS.includes(
              originalConfig.url.split('?')[0]
                  ? originalConfig.url.split('?')[0]
                  : originalConfig.url
          ) &&
          err.response
      ) {
        if (retries > 0 && retries) {
          if (err.response.status === 401) {
            if (originalConfig.url === `/auth/tokens`) {
              TokenService.setTokenRetries(retries - 1);
            }
            originalConfig._retry = true;
            try {
              const rs = await axios.get(`/auth/tokens`);

              const { access_token, refresh_token } = rs.data.data.tokens;
              TokenService.saveLocalRefreshToken(refresh_token);
              TokenService.saveLocalAccessToken(access_token);
              TokenService.setTokenRetries(5);
              return axios(originalConfig);
            } catch (error) {
              return Promise.reject(error);
            }
          } else if (err.response.status === 403) {
            window.location.href = '/login';
          }
        } else {
          const {toast}= (await import('sonner'))
          toast.error('Your session has expired.');
          TokenService.clearStorage();
          //Call for new refresh token
          window.location.href = '/login';
        }
      }
    }
    }

  return Promise.reject(err);
};

const setup = () => {
  axios.interceptors.request.use(
    (request: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => requestHandler(request),
    (error: AxiosError) => Promise.reject(error)
  );

  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response: AxiosResponse) => responseHandler(response),
    (error: AxiosError) => errorHandler(error)
  );
};

export default setup;
```

*CODE For Fetching the Protected API*

```
export const revalidate = 0 // revalidate the data at most every hour
const getPlan = cache(async () => {
  return await axios.get(`/plan/all?page=1&limit=5`)
})
```

Server Functions To Handle Cookies

```
"use server";
import {cookies} from "next/headers";

export const removeServerCookie=async (cookie:string)=>{
    cookies().delete(cookie);
}

export const setServerCookie=async (cookie:string,value:string)=>{
    cookies().delete(cookie);
    cookies().set(cookie,value);
}
```

See the output at first iam getting 401 Error then on refreshing the page api is fetched
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KihgT.png)